# Retrieve specific number of rows in a SQL Server query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

Rows:

```
1  Test1
2  Test2
3  Test3
12 Test4
5  Test1
6  Test2
7  Test1
8  Test2
```

I am trying to achieve export xml data file from ssis package.

An example: I need to create 2 rows per file. What sql command can ensure return correct 2 rows per time if that query in the SSIS loop container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you prepare resultset before, identify pairs (two rows) and then iterate this resultset and created XML output from variable. I don't know complexity of XML you want to prepare, but at least query you can find below could help you prepare pairs identificators, which could be used if you need to obtain more complex data.

Based on your data:

0) prepare variables: data - object, id int, name varchar(20)

1) return your resultset as object - query below prepare pairs with same id (row_group column)

2) iterate with Foreach Ado net enumerator over this object, insert data into variables

3) inside Foreach prepare dataflow task with dynamic filename based on row_group

```
with 
data
as
(
select *, row_number() over(order by id) as row
from test_data
  )
,
pairs
as
(
select * ,
case when row%2=0 then row-1 else row end  as row_group
from data
 )

select id, name, row_group
from pairs
order by row_group
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
Create table Temp (id smallint, Col1 varchar(25))
insert into Temp select 1, 'Test1'
insert into Temp select 2,  'Test2'
insert into Temp select 3,  'Test3'
insert into Temp select 12, 'Test4'
insert into Temp select 5,  'Test1'
insert into Temp select 6,  'Test2'
insert into Temp select 7,  'Test1'
insert into Temp select 8,  'Test2'
insert into Temp select 10, 'Test1'


declare @i int = (select Max(RowNum) from (select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by id) as RowNum,id,Col1 from Temp) as temp)

declare @countnum int = 1
declare @NoOfRows int = 100

while(@countnum <= @i)
begin 

select * from (select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by (select 0)) as RowNum,id,Col1 from Temp) as temp where RowNum >= @countnum and RowNum < @countnum + @NoOfRows

set @countnum = @countnum + @NoOfRows
end

drop table Temp
```

Comment: this seems to be correct. If i want 100 per select. shall I change 2 to 100 ?

Comment: Yes, You can do it for that you have to change condition. I am updating my answer to fullfill your requirement.

Comment: @Coder : Is it fulfill your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or later, you can use the SQL paging enhancement in T-SQL

Please check the below query to see if it helps
Note that @n parameter should be considered as the loop number

```
/*
create table tbl (id smallint, txt varchar(25))
insert into tbl select 1, 'Test1'
insert into tbl select 2,  'Test2'
insert into tbl select 3,  'Test3'
insert into tbl select 12, 'Test4'
insert into tbl select 5,  'Test1'
insert into tbl select 6,  'Test2'
insert into tbl select 7,  'Test1'
insert into tbl select 8,  'Test2'
insert into tbl select 9,  'Test1'
delete tbl where id = 9
*/

declare @rowsperpage int = 2
declare @x int = @rowsperpage
declare @n int = 1

while @x = @rowsperpage
begin

SELECT *
FROM tbl
ORDER BY id
OFFSET (@n-1)*@rowsperpage ROWS
FETCH NEXT @rowsperpage ROWS ONLY

select @x = @@ROWCOUNT
set @n = @n + 1

end
```

You can find more details on [SQL paging using offset and fetch next](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-2012/sql-paging-in-sql-server-2012-sql-order-by-offset-fetch-next-rows.aspx) at referred tutorial

I hope it helps

Comment: I am getting error message: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'.
Msg 153, Level 15, State 2, Line 12
Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? This code will work for SQL2012 and later as I wrote in the original post

Answer (score -1):

use LIMIT to get the correct subset of records from a query:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders LIMIT 10, 2
```

will retrive two records from Orders starting from record 11

Comment: you are right, TOP will do the same. I misread mysql as the db. Only problem is you have to run it twice to select a range: first select the top 12 and then the top 2 of this subset.

Comment: thanks for answering. but i am not sure this is right thing to do.

Comment: Sorry but what is wrong in SELECT TOP 2 * FROM (SELECT TOP 12 * FROM Orders) ??